# Checking internet connection using Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, task

I am trying to execute a background Task that checks the internet connection without blocking the GUI (checking fonction requires 3s to check the connection). If successful (or not) a panel display an image (red or green according to the result).

My code :

```
public Image iconeConnexion;

public Image IconeConnexion
{
    get { return iconeConnexion; }
    set { iconeConnexion = value; }
}

public void myPingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Cancelled || e.Error != null)
    {
        this.iconeConnexion = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.red;
        return;
    }

    if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        this.iconeConnexion = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.green;

}

public void checkInternet()
{
    Ping myPing = new Ping();
    myPing.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(myPingCompletedCallback);
    try
    {
        myPing.SendAsync("google.com", 3000 /*3 secs timeout*/, new byte[32], new PingOptions(64, true));
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

My call in the form load after all the controls loading :

```
Task Parent = new Task(() =>
{
    checkInternet();
    MessageBox.Show("Check");
});

//Start the Task
Parent.Start();
Parent.Wait();
```

Application runs but no images is displayed so far. Can't find out why.

Can you please help me on this one ?

Comment: Did you try debugging the application? It seems an exception should occur when trying to access a UI element from a background thread.

Comment: If you put a break-point on your callback function, does it get called?

Comment: It does call the fonctions. It seems though that the Messagebox appears before the actual call is made... which is why the image is not displayed.

Comment: Why are you starting a task and immediately waiting for it?

Comment: I used it for debugging the end of the task to see if it could come from the task itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there isn't too much information in your question, i assume that when trying to set the UI element from a background thread an exception is being thrown and swallowed by the `Task`.

As pinging a server is an IO bound operation, there is no need to spin off a new thread. This can make things easier in combination with the new [`async-await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) keywords introduced in C# 5.

This is using [`Ping.SendPingAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh159412(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public async Task CheckInternetAsync()
{
    Ping myPing = new Ping();
    try
    {
        var pingReply = await myPing.SendPingAsync("google.com", 3000, new byte[32], new PingOptions(64, true));
        if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
        {
            this.iconeConnexion = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.green;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        this.iconeConnexion = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.red;
    }
}
```

And call it inside your FormLoaded event:

```
public async void FormLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await CheckInternetAsync();
}
```

As a side note:

1. Executing a `Task` and immediately waiting on it usually means you're doing something wrong. If that is the desired behavior, simply consider running the method synchronously.
2. It is always recommended to use `Task.Run` instead of `new Task`. The former returns a *"hot task"* (one which is already started), while the latter returns a *"cold task"* (one which is hasn't started and waits for the `Start` method to called).

Comment: Thanks your codes it worked. I didn't know the newest keywords at all, that was a good lesson.

Comment: By the way, I didn't has a FormLoaded event, I used instead the Shown event but it's all the same.

Comment: On a side note, can I use Task like this to perform repetitive checking on a, let's say, 10 minutes window ?

Comment: @You sure thing, you can set it inside a `while (true)` loop, and use `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));`